# How do you connect to a catalog across web applications (using cross-site publishing)?

Tags: web-application, cross-site-publishing

I've successfully connected catalogs between sites that are in the same web application through cross-site publishing, but can't get this to work with sites that aren't in the same web application.

**Is there a trick to connecting catalogs across web applications?**

I can see the catalog, but when attempting to connect to it, I get an error: "Properties (PROPERTY NAME) specified by the shared catalog could not be found in search schema."